# How Can I Solve it? TypeError: fillna() got an unexpected keyword argument 'implace'

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset, pandas

I am trying to replace NaN values in a given dataset with this

```
import pandas as pd 
import quandl
import math

df.fillna(-9999, implace=True)
```

But I keep on getting this error:

**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "regression.py", line 44, in 
    df.fillna(0,implace=True)

File "/home/compname/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3790, in fillna
    downcast=downcast, **kwargs)

TypeError: fillna() got an unexpected keyword argument 'implace'

**

Comment: You should put inplace not implace :) Welcome ;)

Comment: Can someone flag this as a typo and off topic (because this belongs to SO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, change *implace* for *inplace* (change the *m* for the *n*)

Comment: @Kizito if you have a programming question, go to stackoverflow, that's where these questions should be asked, not here.